# Make sprite bounce back

Tags: c++, directx, sprite

I'm playing a little around with DirectX 9.0 and want a object to bounce back when it hits the screen edges (top,bottom,right and left). The sprite is an image that is 128x128 pixels.
I manage to make it bounce back and forth, but this does not happend before the image is either half outside the screen, or too early. This is because the object it self is in the middle of the image, is there anyway to "remove" the background part so the program does not bounce back the sprite before the image part itself collides with the screen edge?
Do I have to modify the image manually? Like cropping it or something=

Here is some of the code I'm working with:

```
if(this->Textures[i].posision.x >= this->_screenWidth)
{
    this->Textures[i].right = false;
}
else if(this->Textures[i].posision.x <= 0)
{
    this->Textures[i].right = true;
}

if(!this->Textures[i].right)
    this->Textures[i].posision.x -= 0.3f;
else
    this->Textures[i].posision.x += 0.3f;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if you're travelling with a left-ward vector, a collision would be qualified as:

```
if(this->Textures[i].posision.x - 128/2 <= 0)
{
    this->Textures[i].right = true;
}
```

if your position.x and position.y refer to the centre of the image, then all you have to do is add/subtract half the image size to get the bounds of your image.
If your sprite isn't filling up your image, then you should probably crop some of it out.